# NRI-FLEX Integration Unable to Return the Correct Headers

Tags: monitoring, newrelic

I am trying to create a NRI-FLEX integration that essentially reports back weather or not a specific service is up or not by curling the service's availability page (https://example.com/meta/availability). The regular curl command brings up to much unneeded information so I've been using the following command:

```
curl -s -i example.com/meta/availability | grep -E 'HTTP|Availability Check'
```

Which results in the following output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pu2S.png)

Here is what I have so far:

```
integrations:
  - name: nri-flex
    interval: 60s
    timeout: 10s
    config:
      name: Example_Availability
      apis:
        - name: Example_Availability
          commands:
            - name: ExampleServices-Availability
              run: curl -s -i https://example.com/meta/availability | grep -E 'HTTP|Availability Check'
              return_headers: true
              regex_matches:
                - expression: HTTP/1.1 (\d+)
                  keys:
                    [HTTP/1.1]
                - expression: Availability Check (\w+)
                  keys:
                    [Availability Check]
          custom_attributes:
            Url: https://example.com/meta/availability
```

This results in the following output when I query it in New Relic:
[Bad Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuF39.png)
For some reason it takes the first character of the header as the title and displays everything else as the result.
I would like the results to look more like this:

| Status Code | Availability Check |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | Passed |
| 200 | Passed |

I've tried playing around with the regex expressions and using a few of different functions in I found in the various examples found here: https://github.com/newrelic/nri-flex/tree/master/examples
but nothing has worked so far. I either get the output from the screenshot or the flex integration stops working.

Agent Version: 1.50.0
Integration Version: 1.10.0

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

creator of Flex here.

The difference in your config vs. the examples is you are missing `split_output`, this is to help Flex know when to start parsing as well as if there is continuous blocks of similar data.

With your availability check expression you are missing a colon as well so this would never work.

I updated your command to output some more data to use as an example, and my curl output is slightly different from yours also.
`curl -s -i https://example.com/meta/availability | grep -E 'HTTP|Availability Check|accept'`

[my example curl output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bx08.png)

Updated Config

[example output w/ new config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huWrC.png)

Adjust below for your needs/format

```html
integrations:
  - name: nri-flex
    interval: 60s
    timeout: 10s
    config:
      name: example
      apis:
        - name: Example_Availability
          commands:
            - name: ExampleServices-Availability
              run: curl -s -i https://example.com/meta/availability | grep -E 'HTTP|Availability Check|accept'
              split_output: HTTP
              regex_matches:
                - expression: 'HTTP\/1.1 (\d+)'
                  keys:
                    [HTTP/1.1]
                - expression: 'HTTP\/2 (\d+)'
                  keys:
                    [HTTP/2]
                - expression: 'Availability Check: (\w+)'
                  keys:
                    [Availability Check]
                - expression: 'accept-ranges: (\w+)'
                  keys:
                    [acceptRanges]
```